# How can you dynamically change the disabled property of a Sencha text field?

Tags: extjs, textfield

I have a formPanel set up with a text field. When a button is pressed, I would like it to change the disabled property of the text field from true to false, allowing it to be editable. The problem is that I don't know how to make this stick. Here's the form code:

```
myApp.views.formContainer = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        id: 'inspectionForm',
        layout: 'vbox',
        width: '100%',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'myText',
                id: 'myText',
                label: 'License Plate',
                width: '90%'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Submit',
                height: 40,
                ui: 'confirm-round',
                handler: function()
                {
                    Ext.get('myText').disabled = false;
                }
            }]
});
```

The thing about `Ext.get('mytext'),disabled = false;` is that it works. Checking it later shows that the disabled attribute is set to false. But you still can't edit it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling `Ext.getCmp('mytext').disabled = false;` you only change the initial config property. To actually modify the component use `Ext.getCmp('mytext').enable();` and `Ext.getCmp('mytext').disable();`

Comment: I changed it and got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'enable'". Am I missing something?

Comment: It would be `Ext.getCmp('myText')`. `Ext.get()` gets a DOM element not Sencha component. Also, using `Ext.getCmp()` to access components is not the optimal technique in Sencha/ExtJS. See this scrrencast for more details: http://extjsinaction.com/258